# Reading and text matching Outlook .msg file in Perl

Tags: perl, outlook, msg

I am having trouble text matching .msg files using Perl. The first block of code works to print the entire message, but I just need the file name if it contains a certain string.

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Email::Outlook::Message;
    use Email::MIME;

    my $sourceDir = "c:/temp";

    open_msg("test.msg");

    sub open_msg {
       my $verbose = 0;
       my $msgFile = shift;
       my $origMsg = new Email::Outlook::Message "$sourceDir/$msgFile", $verbose or die "$!";
       my $mime = $origMsg->to_email_mime;
       print $mime->as_string;
       return ($origMsg);
    }
```

The .msg files are in a folder (on Windows). I have used below code to print the file names of .txt files, but I need to use something similar for .msg files.

```
#works for .txt files
my @files = glob "C:/temp";

foreach my $file (@files) {
open   (FILE, "$file");
while(my $line= <FILE> ){
    print "$file" if $line =~ /test_string/;
}
close FILE; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any `.msg` file handy to test with but how about replacing this line:

```
print $mime->as_string;
```

...with a statement like this?

```
print $mime->as_string if $mime->as_string =~ /test_string/;
```

This should do the trick as far as "print its contents if it contains test_string" is concerned.

If you also want to loop over the whole list of `*.msg` files, try something like this:

```
my @files = glob "C:/temp";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open_msg($file);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear! :) Feel free to use the green checkmark to "mark as answer" if you would like to give me some more points. ;)